# Why do we need to know the address of shellcode?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I have read many articles regarding the buffer overflow exploit. Everywhere its written as follow.

> "It's difficult to know the starting address of the shellcode"

Why do we need to know the address of the shellcode? Why does stack not execute the shellcode as it is?

say we inject our shellcode this way

**our shellcode -- some padding -- our choice of saved return
address**

should the shellcode not be executed by default by the stack? Why do we add NOP sleds and complicate things.

Comment: Can you link one of those articles? Maybe there's something specific there. I think with the current information you provide it's difficult to correctly answer your questions.

Comment: Following @perror answer, you can use address containing `0x90` as return address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploiting a software by injecting a shellcode in its memory always requires the following steps:

1. Have a way to inject your shellcode in memory (usually, it can take place in any buffer of the program).
2. Redirect the execution flow (i.e. be able to write on the `rip`) to point to the shellcode and execute it (usually, it is done through a buffer-overflow).

If you are not sure about the address of your shellcode, the second part of the exploitation (the redirection of the `eip`) cannot be achieved reliably.